# How to move a list item to a specified index(position) in an unordered list using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, html-lists

Lets say I've a following unordered list, How can I move "Three" to any index(position) in the list? 
The approach should be dynamic. Replacing the text content of an element is not an option. Because each list item will be containing other elements as well.

```
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
  .
  .
  .
  <li>Hundred</li>  /* Nth List Element */
</ul>
```

Tried solutions from already answered similar questions. But didn't get the desired result.

I've already tried this

1. Fetching the list in an Array through jQuery
2. Used array.each to traverse the array
3. Then used prepend to move the particular li to the top of the list

But through this approach I can only move the li element to the top of list. Not at any desired position.

Comment: You can use nth child selector and cross overwrite them with .text() between src and target li https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/

Comment: I want to move the whole li element to a new position. As it will be containing more elements in itself, So replacing its text content wouldn't be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a constructor with an index based method for this:

```js
function LiMover(liParent){
  this.kids = liParent.children;
  this.move = (index, beforeIndex = null)=>{
    const k = this.kids, e = k[index];
    if(beforeIndex === null){
      liParent.appendChild(e)
    }
    else{
      liParent.insertBefore(e, k[beforeIndex]);
    }
    return this;
  }
}
const liMover = new LiMover(document.querySelector('ul'));
liMover.move(0); // move 0 index (one) after last index
liMover.move(5, 0); // move 5 index (one) back to 0 index
liMover.move(1, 4); // move 1 index (two) to 4 index
liMover.move(3, 5).move(2, 0); // showing return this chain
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: Solves the issue!

Answer (score 2):

```js
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const items = [...ul.querySelectorAll('li')];

const moveItem = (from, to) => {
  if (to > items.length - 1 || to < 0) return;
  
  const item = items[from];
  if (!item) return;
  
  ul.removeChild(item);
  ul.insertBefore(item, ul.children[to]);
}

moveItem(5, 0);
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>  
</ul>
```

Comment: You don't have to `.removeChild` if you're moving an Element. It's an Object.

Comment: @StackSlave I think it is necessary. If you try `moveItem(0, 5)` without first removing the item, the first item will be moved before index 5, and not into position 5. You can also see this if you try `liMover.move(5, 0)` in your answer.

Comment: Solves the issue!

Answer (score 0):

It's of course solvable. I have implemented a function which swaps two items of a collection:

```
function swap(items, first, second) {
    var aux = items[first].innerHTML;
    items[first].innerHTML = items[second].innerHTML;
    items[second].innerHTML = aux;
}

swap(document.querySelectorAll("ul > li"), 2, 4);
```

See the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/5qropsvu/

Comment: Your code does not actually swap the Elements. It just changes the `.innerHTML`. That is not the same thing at all. If the Elements have Events on them, this is going to be an issue.

Comment: what about when each li has some classes and maybe an id, those are out of the `.innerHTML`, so you should use `.outerHTML` instead

Comment: @StackSlave You're right! you understand my question correctly.

Comment: Swapping values is not an option. As li can contain anything in itself.

Answer (score 0):

try this swapping

```
  const listElts = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('li'));
  const swap1 = listElts[2].textContent;
  const swap2 = listElts[4].textContent;
  listElts[2].textContent = swap2;
  listElts[4].textContent = swap1;
```